# working out lower bound of algorithms

Tags: algorithm

Below is the pseudo code from chapter 4 of the book I am studying with.

I have worked out its basically finds a counterfeit coin if there is one because it will be lighter than the normal coins.

```
CW(A, i, j) /* n coins */
{
    if (i==j) return i /* base case */
    k := (j-i+1)/3
    Weigh A[i..i+k-1] and A[i+k..i+2k-1]
    if A[i..i+k-1] lighter
    CW(A, i, i+k-1);
    else if A[i+k..i+2k-1] lighter
    CW(A, i+k, i+2k-1);
    else /* equal */
    CW(A, i+2k, j);
}
```

Now I have 2 questions about this.

1. How do I show a lower bound on the number of weighings necessary to find the counterfeit coin, or to determine that none exists?
2. Is there a better algorithm to find the counterfeit coin using as few weightings as possible?

Answer (score 1):

While you didn't specify what the actual problem is, I assume you have `n` coins, exactly one of which is lighter than the others, and need to find it using a balance scale which can compare groups of coins.

To find a lower bound, consider the fact that each weighing only has 3 possible outcomes. So `k` weighings can distinguish between 3<sup>k</sup> different cases. Since there are `n` possible cases in the given problem (`n` possible choices for the counterfeit coin), you will need at least k=log<sub>3</sub>n weighings to find it.

If you analyze the given algorithm, you will see that this is the number of weighings that it uses, so it is optimal.

Comment: yes sorry, n number of coins and there might or might not be a fake coin among them. this is why im having trouble working out this problem.

Comment: also the book says that there is a better algorithm to work this problem out then the above example, yet it did not show this in the book??? so this was my second question as i believe this algorithm is perfect.

Comment: @alex The algorithm is optimal in terms of number of weighings in the worst case, so it can't be improved in that regard.